# How does `int sum = n + - + - + - + n` compile where `n` is an `int`?

Tags: c, operators, arithmetic-expressions

This afternoon, I really don't know what I was doing with Operators and C.  Eventually, I wrote some code which I was thinking wouldn't compile, But I don't know how it worked.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n=2;
    int sum = n + - + - + - + n;  /* This line */
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

> 0

I am completely confused how the code compiled and what is happening behind the scene.

How does the line `int sum = n + - + - + - + n;` work?

Comment: Do you know unary opeartors?

Comment: Most of those are unary operators.

Comment: Yes i know but i am completely confused how it is working i also tried some different variants of the same code but still working.

Comment: The unary + operator is usually rather confusing, as it has very limited practical use. It is mainly just there in the language to make it consistent with the far more useful unary - operator.

Comment: Who would write code like this, (if not a prof/TA)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int sum = n + - + - + - + n;
/*          b u u u u u u   */
/* Order:   7 6 5 4 3 2 1   */
```

is equivalent to:

```
n + (-(+(-(+(-(+n))))));
```

or simply `n + (-n)`

Note that unary operators bind more tightly than binary operators in `C opeartor precedance table` and associativity of unary operator `+-` is from right to left while of binary `+-` operators in from left to right.

Answer (score 5):

All but the first are just *unary operators*.

```
n + - + - + - + n
```

is equivalent to

```
n + (-(+(-(+(-(+n))))))
```

which is in turn simply equal to

```
n + (-n)
```

after resolving all the unary operators.

`-n` is, of course, ordinary negation; `+n` does essentially nothing (though it has the side effect of forcing integral promotion).

Comment: and how this would evaluate  sum = n - - - n + - n;

Comment: @PankajPrakash `--` will become a different  operator without space because of maximal crunch rule.

Comment: @PankajPrakash Figure it out yourself - it's a good exercise.

Comment: @MohitJain: There are spaces, so it will parse as two unary operators.

Comment: @nneonneo OK, spaces are hard to spot

Comment: int sum = n - - - n + - n; is evaluating to -2. While when the same line with parenthesis     int sum = n - (- (- (n + (- n)))); evaluates to 2.

Comment: Then you have the wrong evaluation. Note that unary operators bind "tighter" than binary operators. Try again!

Comment: @nneonneo wouldn't int sum = n - - - n + - n; is evaluated as int sum = n - (- (- (n + (- n))));

Answer (score 3):

Both of `+` and `-` are also unary operators. The result of `+n` is the (promoted) value of `n`. The result of `-n` is the negative of (promoted) `n`.

```
n + - + - + - + n;
```

is equivalent to:

```
n + (-(+(-(+(-(+n))))))
```

which is basically `n + (-n)` assuming no overflow happens.